# Need alert when the system is going down

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, centos7, rhel6

I need a small alarm (HTTP req or any) when the server is going down. I checked many applications like nagios, servercheck and so on... All these application monitor only remote servers. I have only two servers to monitor. So if my server (10.172.65.124) is going down cant it send a alarm. I dont want to maintain one more server to monitor this. I am using rhel6 & centos7. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python script that will serve the purpose.  It uses sendmail to send your email which will require running it from a linux server that has sendmail enabled.  Change the url to point to the url you are monitoring.  If you run this script, it'll check stackoverflow.

This uses urllib to check the status code it receives when trying to load your url.  If it gets a status other than 200 from the HTTP request it expects the site to be down.

To monitor your server you should run the script on a server or desktop that is independent from your webhost, otherwise you won't be alerted when your server crashes due to a number of reasons.

```
#Import time to allow you to sleep the script, urllib to load the site, subprocess will allow you to run a process on the machine outside of the script (in this instance it's send mail) 
import time
import urllib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#The url being monitored.
url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

#The contents of the email
msg = MIMEText(url + " is not responding.  Please investigate.")
msg["From"] = "me@youremail.com"
msg["To"] = "me@youremail.com"
msg["Subject"] = url + "is not responding"

#This loops while the script is running.
# It gets the status returned from the urllib call, if it's not 200 it will email the email contents above.  
while True:
    status = urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()

    if status <> 200:
        #This is what sends the email.  If you don't have sendmail then update this. 
        p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
        p.communicate(msg.as_string())
    #The number of seconds the loop will pause for before checking again.  I set it to 60. 
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Very good answer. And very good explanation. Thanks for the reply. But I need to monitor from inside the system. But not outside of the system. Can we do that???

Comment: No problem Ravi. Can you clarify when you mean when you say you want to monitor from inside the system? Do you mean you want the http service to tell you when it crashes, or when it has shut down gracefully?  One suggestion I'd have is to create a log parser to grep the error.log which will tell you what's happening with the service but that's again outside the system. Or you could do something like whats referenced here: https://serverfault.com/questions/16243/shell-script-to-execute-something-when-one-of-the-daemon-dies

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend create simple script to ping the machine (they can monitor each other)and if ping timesout send an email.

something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVERIP=IP ADDRESS
NOTIFYEMAIL=test@example.com

ping -c 3 $SERVERIP > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  # Use your favorite mailer here:
  mailx -s "Server $SERVERIP is down" -t "$NOTIFYEMAIL" < /dev/null 
fi
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I dont want to monitor my server from outside. Can we do anything inside the server.

Comment: Externally is a better option if you would have network outage or machine will crash the machine not tell you that it crashing, at least to my knowledge. that why i said if you only have 2 servers you can set them up to monitor each other so if one dies the other can send notification.

Comment: In my case both systems are connected to same switch, same powercard, and same load. If one is going down eventually both will go down

Comment: What you asking is to Operating system monitor itself and when something is wrong either network connection, or system crashes to send you and email. That is impossible, it's like asking a dead person stranded on an deserted island to send you a message. You need an outside source to monitor this environment. There is something called IPMI  that can be installed on the motherboard that provides the monitoring independent of the OS. but motherboard needs to support it and also, if network goes down it wont be able to send you message, same goes for power outage.

Answer (score 0):

As given above script you can configure normal bash script to monitor server http request or any other service request so if it would not get reply then you will get mail.

There is normal application for monitoring web service which is free on limited no of site per user which you can also use this.

http://uptimerobot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Below script will check for the operation state of interface, If you need add some interfaces do alert as per your wish

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
        if [ $(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate) != "up" ]; then
                sleep 1
                #send mail for logging
        fi
done
```